# How PDFSmartCopy from iText detects same resources?

Tags: pdf, itext

I would like to know without deeply digging myself into PDF Smart Copy source code hwhat kind of the "same" resources is able to detect and reuse.

With subsetted fonts and different barcodes I understand that it is nearly impossible and PDFSmartCopy does not detect it.

But what about images and forms - how it will check the "same" resource ?

Does anybody can briefly describe what heuristic is used and which kind of resources in PDF are checked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [great answer directly on the iText website](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/122) about this:

> How is this possible? PdfSmartCopy takes a hash of every stream object that is encountered and keeps those hashes in memory. If PdfSmartCopy detects that you try to add the same stream twice, a reference to the first stream will be used instead of adding a redundant stream.

Comment: Thanks, I probably overlooked it on itext site.